# rpivotTable: remove unnecessary aggregators

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, rpivottable

I create a interactive pivot table by using `rpivotTable` package. However, I found that some of aggregators and renderName are unnecessary for my users. I would like to remove them. For example, I want to remove "Average" from aggregator dropdown menu.

Here is my example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
df <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(

fluidRow(
column(width=10, rpivotTableOutput("pivot"))
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$pivot<-renderRpivotTable({

rpivotTable(df,
            rendererName="Heatmap",
            cols=c("Species"),
            rows=c("Petal.Width"),
            aggregatorName="Count",
            hiddenFromAggregators=["Average"]
)


 })

 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I noticed that there seems some relevant parameters called "hiddenFromAggregators" but I cannot figure out how to apply it in R/Shiny environment.

Here is where I found "hiddenFromAggregators".

https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters

Comment: I guess the problem you are dealing with is addressed in this [issue](https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable/issues/79).

Comment: Thanks, @SBista. Yes, this is what I want. Any idea that this issue can be handled through CSS? I appreciate you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this :

```
rpivotTable(iris, 
            rendererName = "Treemap",
            cols = c("Species"),
            rows = c("Petal.Width"),
            aggregatorName = "Count",
            aggregators = list(Sum = htmlwidgets::JS('$.pivotUtilities.aggregators["Sum"]'),
                               Count = htmlwidgets::JS('$.pivotUtilities.aggregators["Count"]')),
            subtotals = TRUE)
```

There is probably a faster way than adding aggregators one by one (using full pivotUtilities.aggregators)

I couldn't find a full list of the default aggregators but you can get it with web inspector on your app (with Google Chrome: right click > inspect) and typing `$.pivotUtilities.aggregators` in the console tab.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome!!!! Thank you so much for this solution. I really appreciate it! This is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: I found information on aggregators here: https://pivottable.js.org/examples/onrefresh.html

Answer (score 3):

The `hiddenFromAggregators` parameter affects which dataset attributes are eligible to be used as arguments to aggregators, rather than which aggregators are available. It is rather challenging in `rpivotTable` to pass in a custom set of aggregators but might be possible using something similar to the approach here: https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable/issues/81

You will need to familiarize yourself with the documentation here first: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Aggregators

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your suggestions.